# XPATH based on multiple adjacent values

Tags: python, xml, xpath

What is the following syntax to do the following correctly?

```
title_node.find("EST/EST_Version
                       [Master_Type_HD_SD='HD'] AND [Version_Type='Standard']
                     /Vendor_ID").text
```

Here is how the xml might look:

```
<EST_Version>
  <Vendor_ID>1660023-200455</Vendor_ID>
  <Version_Type>Standard</Version_Type>
  <Master_Type_HD_SD>SD</Master_Type_HD_SD>
</EST_Version>
```

This is essentially what I am trying to do (although the following is incorrect)

```
title_nod.find("EST/EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='SD']/../
                   EST_Version[Version_Type='Directors Cut']/Vendor_ID").text
```

Comment: So only if `Vendor_ID` appears as the next child node of `EST_Version` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple predicate filters (the square brackets), do not combine them with `and`. Simply use them sequentially. The first predicate filter is applied to the set and then the next predicate filter is applied:

```
EST/EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD'][Version_Type='Standard']/Vendor_ID
```

In a single predicate filter, you would use `and` for multiple criteria:

```
EST/EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD' and Version_Type='Standard']/Vendor_ID
```